# How to get message property of an error returned from an express server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux

I'm returning an error response from express like below.

```
    router.post("/", authCheck, authCheckAdmin, (req, res, next) => {
      const burger = new Burger({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        ...req.body
      });

      console.log(burger);

      Burger.find({ name: req.body.name })
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
          if (!result) {
            burger
              .save()
              .then(result => {
                res.status(201).json({
                  message: "Burger Successully Created",
                  burger: result
                });
              })
              .catch(error => {
                res.status(500).json(new Error('Something went wrong when saving the burger')); // <------
              });
          } else {

                 res.status(500).json(new Error('Burger already exist'));
          }
        });
    });
```

This is the React code

```
  export const addBurger = burgerData => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const currentState = getState();

    axios
      .post("/burgers", burgerData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentState.auth.token}`
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message); <-------- Here
      });
  };
```

Below is the console preview

[image]

How can I get the message that I have passed inside express? I want to get "Burger already exist" as the error message. Is there another way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Could you show the response of the request from the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Server side fix

```
res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, `error` is not defined in the last `else` of your `Burger.find` method which is causing this error. This type of error's are mostly server side errors. Hope this work for you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I fixed it. But it's not the issue. How can I access the error object on frontend side? When I get error.message, it's the 500 server error is the one I get. Not the one I passed.

Comment: You can write an interceptor for that which will catch such errors and return the custom error message that you pass.

Comment: Is there any way to access the error without writing an interceptor?

Comment: According to me not really, because the server will crash in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
res.status(500).json(new Error('Burger already exiist')); // <------
```

if you would look at response in dev tools, you see that in this case payload is empty object. So you need directly tell the server what you need to send back. Try this if you already waiting for `message` key in react part:

```
res.status(500).json({message: 'Burger already exist'});
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry. It gives the same thing. It gives me "Request failed with status code 500" , not the one I passed.

Comment: First, please try to change returned status from current 500 to any other - check if you see response from here at all, not from any other error. 
Second, I suggest you need to run your server under debugger with few breakpoints around. Probably the issue is not exactly here, it's hard to tell without any logs and any additional info

Comment: all the other end points are working perfect. Only the errors are not passed properly.

Comment: have you tried changing 500 in both your response cases? make them temporary be any **different** statuses (like, 404 and 400) just to make sure that response you're seeing is yours, and not default server issue resp. Then it will be easier to find out what is wrong